# Frontend upload of multiple files in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I recently got a WP-site in my lap because I knew the most about "computers" ;) The site works fine but one thing we would like to add to the site is a possibility for users to upload pictures which then can be added to galleries by moderators/admins.

I found a plugin for this https://wordpress.org/plugins/frontend-uploader/

But the problem is I can only make it upload one picture at a time. What we really would like is to present a page where you could either upload many files at once or better yet just drag and drop in files.

There doesn't seem to be a plugin for this usecase and all my googling has only led me to sites like

http://kvcodes.com/2013/12/create-front-end-multiple-file-upload-wordpress/

which describe how you could build this functionality yourself. So I have two questions

Is there really no plugin for this? In my mind this is a really common usecase and I can't see why there shouldn't be a plugin for it.

If I have to build it myself then how do I go about doing it? I know my way around programing and a terminal but I don't know squat about wordpress (yet :)). Eg. if you look at the "tutorial" in the above link it has some html and some php but where do I put this inside my wp-installation? Do I create a plugin with the php-files and then publish a page containing the html using the admin backend? or...? Most examples I find about building your own stuff for wordpress gives you some html and some php-example code but nowhere do they explain where to put it.

I could probably find this out by trial and error but I was hoping to speed this up a bit by asking :)

Answer (score 1):

The plugin is mine. The post you highlighted is also mine.

If you need to make a plugin with it. I can help you.